# how to add column index to Parquet output from Apache Beam Python SDK?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying to batch process .avro files from GCS and write the result as Parquet files back to GCS, the data is a timeseries and elements are timestamped. How can I make a column index from the `timestamp` column in the Parquet output? in Pandas/Dask its a simple `.set_index('timestamp')` statement..

```
class AddTimestampDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, element['timestamp'])


with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    p = pipeline | 'ReadAvro' >> beam.io.ReadFromAvro(
        'gs://input/*.avro')

    timestamped_items = p | 'timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())
    fixed_windowed_items = (timestamped_items | 'window' >> 
                           beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60)))
    processed_items = fixed_windowed_items | 'compute' >> beam.ParDo(
                      ComputeDoFn())

    _ = processed_items | beam.io.WriteToParquet('gs://output/out.parquet',
                                            pyarrow.schema(
                                                [
                                                    ('timestamp',
                                                     pyarrow.timestamp('s')), ........
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? As far as I understand, Parquet files don't have column indices (though they do store stats on chunks/pages for quicker filtering).

Comment: @robertwb Parquet has column index since v2.50 https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/CHANGES.md#version-250. I want the index for time range queries with Dask/Pandas. if i set_index in Dask and write to Parquet it does set timestamp as an index column. this is an expensive operation for large data so i prefer to do it in write time..

Comment: We use arrow's ParquetWriter [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We beam.io.WriteToParquet uses arrow's [ParquetWriter](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.31.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/parquetio.py#L525) to write parquet files. I'm not seeing any way to set the index with this writer. However, you could use Beam's [Dataframe support](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) to convert your PCollection to a Dataframe, set the index, and then call `to_parquet(...)` which delegates to the underlying pandas implementation and should write indices out.

Comment: will converting a PCollection to a Dataframe try to load the entire dataset into RAM?

Comment: No it won't load the entire thing into RAM. Beam's to_dataframe creates a deferred Dataframe object that's backed by a (distributed) PCollection of dataframes.